# how to disable intellij services tool window

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Well.. this is silly, but i've been struggling with it for hours.
I switched by mistake to services tool window following Intellij pop-up suggestion. Now I want to get back to the normal debug mode, but I can't find a way.

No matter what i try, when i hit the debug button, it's processing everything in the "Services" tool window, and "Debug" tool window is disabled saying "nothing to show".

Intellij version 2021.1

Please advise!
Thank you

Comment: You can search in actions window with `Show Services Tree`. You can disable that i think

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just remove run configuration type from services tool window:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! You're my hero

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for this for a while - it's sad that it is not properly documented anywhere... :(

Comment: You might need to enable "Group By" -> "Service Groups" to see "Delete" option.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like the services view at all. This saves me from clicking around and creates a lot more clearity.